# How to create a new array from an existing array such that all data of same index will be together under that index key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've an associative array titled `$_POST`. This array is dynamic in nature that is it can contain any no. of elements. For your reference I've generated the `$_POST` array with only two elements. The content of this array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [op] => preview
    [id] => 
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [company_id] => 46
    [product_id_1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 9
        )

    [pack] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 50
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 60
        )

    [volume] => Array
        (
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 70
        )

    [units] => Array
        (
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 12
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 80
        )

    [rebate_start_date] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2014-05-01
            [2] => 2014-06-01
        )

    [rebate_expiry_date] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2014-05-31
            [2] => 2014-06-30
        )

    [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 10
                    [3] => 15
                    [4] => 17
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 44
                    [1] => 45
                    [2] => 47
                    [3] => 49
                    [4] => 50
                )

        )

    [multiselect] => 50
    [rebate_total_count] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5000
            [2] => 10000
        )

    [product_id_2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 8
        )

)
```

Now I want a new array in such a way that all the data of same index should be under a key whose value is equal to that index. If you get confused with my requirement take a look at the following array which I want to generate:

```
Array
  (
    [op] => preview
    [id] => 
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [company_id] => 46    
    [1] => Array 
        (
        [pack] => 10
        [quantity] => 20
        [volume] => 30
        [units] => 7
        [amount] => 40
        [rebate_start_date] => 2014-05-01
        [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-05-31
        [rebate_total_count] => 5000
        [applicable_states] => Array 
                (
                 [0] => 3
                 [1] => 4
                 [2] => 10
                 [3] => 15
                 [4] => 17
                )   
        [product_id_1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 9
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
      (
        [pack] => 50
        [quantity] => 60
        [volume] => 70  
        [units] => 12
        [amount] => 80    
        [rebate_start_date] => 2014-06-01
        [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-06-30
        [rebate_total_count] => 10000
        [applicable_states] => Array 
          (
            [0] => 44
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 47
            [3] => 49
            [4] => 50
          )
        [product_id_2] => Array
          (
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 8
          )
      )

      [multiselect] => 50
)
```

In above array you can observe that all the data of matching index is under same key. One more thing I want to tell you that the keys `[applicable_states]` and `[rebate_total_count]` may contain blank values. This thing also should be considered while manipulating the array `$_POST` in order to generate the array containing all data of same index under one key as above. How to achieve this in optimum way by using ready made array functions and some magical logic in PHP? Thank You.

Comment: Some maps and filtering. What did you try? Cos SO is not a code generator

Comment: how is `[pack]` related to `[product_id_1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (!is_array($val)) {
        $new_array[$key] = $val;
    } elseif (preg_match('/^product_id_(\d+)$/', $key, $match)) {
        $i = $match[1];
        if (isset($new_array[$i])) {
            $new_array[$i][$key] = $val;
        } else {
            $new_array[$i] = array($key => $val);
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($val as $i => $subval) {
            if (isset($new_array[$i])) {
                $new_array[$i][$key] = $subval;
            } else {
                $new_array[$i] = array($key => $subval);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all Thank you so much for your help. I tried your code. It's giving me almost the same I wanted but it has only on small bug in output. The elements under key [product_id_1] and [product_id_2] are not printing correctly. If you want I can show you the array generated. Should I append the generated array to the question body?

Comment: Why are `product_id_N` treated differently from all the other arrays?

Comment: This is to avoid the HTML elements with same name.

Comment: You should clarify the question to say that these entries don't follow the same rule that all entries with a matching index are under the same key.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll always keep in mind from now onwards.